# Google sheets category/row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a similar looking Google sheet as shown below. There are thousands of rows and dozens of categories across the sheet. I would like a way of finding all rows which have not been categorised, i.e. where there is no "Y" in any of the category columns C, D, E. In the sheet below for example, row 3 has not been categorised.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=byrow(C2:E,lambda(Σ,if(and(counta(Σ)=0,len(offset(index(Σ,,1),,-2))),"NOT_CATEGORIZED_",)))
```

[image]

*if you wish to filter those specific rows on separate:*

```js
=filter(A:B,len(A:A),byrow(C:E,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ)=0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula to return the row numbers of the rows that have not been categorized.

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(ROW(C:E),B:B,""=BYROW(C:E,LAMBDA(r,JOIN(,r)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=FILTER(A2:B,BYROW(C2:E,LAMBDA(x,AND(INDEX((x=""))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This can be shortened to: `=FILTER(A2:B,BYROW(C2:E,LAMBDA(x,AND(x=""))))` since FILTER is array-enabling.

Comment: @ztiaa Yap. You are correct!